# WooCommerce Custom shortode : Avoid problems with Elementor editor

Tags: object, woocommerce, methods, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I’m using the code below in my theme's functions.php file to be able to output the Product SKU in various places all over my templates with `[woo_sku]` shortcode. While this works fine, I can’t access the template editor (Elementor) without uncommenting the function, as there is no product context in the template and the error prevents the editor from loading.

Is there a way to catch the error and return an empty value when not in a product context?

```
function display_woo_sku() {
    global $product;
    return $product->get_sku();
}
add_shortcode( 'woo_sku', 'display_woo_sku' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that problem, what you can do is:

- First check that `$product` is a `WC_Product` Object using [`is_a()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) PHP function,
- Then also check that the `get_sku()` method exist for the `WC_Product` object using [`method_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) PHP function.

You will use both of them in an `IF` statement like:

```
function display_woo_sku() {
    global $product;
    
    if( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) && method_exists( $product, 'get_sku' ) ) {
        return $product->get_sku();
    } else {
        return  '';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'woo_sku', 'display_woo_sku' );
```

It should better work now.

Comment: C'est parfait, merci bien ,-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code now, it appears to work (though Loic's code above seemed to make more sense, imho :)

```
function display_woo_sku() { 
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        return 'no SKU';
    }
    global $product; 
    return $product->get_sku(); 
    } 
add_shortcode( 'woo_sku', 'display_woo_sku' );
```

Comment: Yes you can use of course `if ( ! is_product() ) {`. Or may be  `global $product;` first and simply `if ( ! $product ) {` after it...